# Criando o arquivo “persistence.xml” JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Gostaria de saber se existe um forma de configuração a criação(as configurações) do  `persistence.xml` no momento da criação do projeto.

Exemplo do aqruivo:

```
<!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> 
  <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

gostaria alterar a propriedade

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

para

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Apenas de `value="create-drop"` para `value="update"`

Comment: André, vc quer que todas as vezes que vc criar um novo projeto o valor da propriedade ``hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`` seja ``update``?

Comment: Tiago, isso mesmo !

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta é que se trata de automação.

**Podemos automatizar o processo de criação de projetos** de muitas formas, mas vou me concentrar e usar os recursos da ferramenta Maven. Assumirei que tomaremos um novo projeto do zero como modelo. A solução é bem mais ampla do que apenas a criação do arquivo de configuração do arquivo `persistence.xml`.

**Construindo um Arquétipo** [[**Balaji Varanasi, Sudha Belida -  2014**](https://www.apress.com/us/search?query=Introducing+Maven), 49 p.]

1) Crie o projeto: `seu-archetype-app-modelo`

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp  \
-DgroupId=br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo \
-DartifactId=seu-archetype-app-modelo \
-DgeneratePom=true \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Acesse a pasta: `seu-archetype-app-modelo`.

2) Crie a pasta `src/META-INF/` e o seu arquivo `src/META-INF/persistence.xml`, com as suas configurações.

**Exemplo**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jasper_book_chapter_4" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                     value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> 
            <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

3) Modifique o arquico `pom.xml` conforme sua necessidade. No exemplo aqui, definiremos o plugin: `tomcat7-maven-plugin` e a dependencia: Servlet 3.0.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo</groupId>
  <artifactId>seu-archetype-app-modelo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>seu-archetype-app-modelo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>seu-archetype-app-modelo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

4) Crie as pastas `test/java` e `test/resources` na pasta `src` similar a estrutura da pasta `src/main`.

5) Criar o package `br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo.web.servlet` (tem que ser o mesmo pacote do comando acima `-DgroupId=br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo`) na pasta `src/main/java`.

Execute o seguinte comando:

```
$mkdir -p br/com/seu_archetype_app_modelo/web/servlet
```

<sub>**NOTA <sup>1</sup>**: criar a mesma estrutura de pacotes na pasta `src/test/java`.</sub>

6) Criar o arquivo: `AppStatusServlet.java` no pacote: `br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo.web.servlet`;

```
package br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo.web.servlet;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

@WebServlet("/status")
public class AppStatusServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws IOException {

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("OK");
    response.setStatus(response.SC_OK);

  } 
}
```

Aqui neste passo já temos o projeto modelo pronto. Volte para pasta: `seu-archetype-app-modelo`.

7) Execute o comando:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

Após terminar o comando acima, será criada a `seu-archetype-app-modelo/target/generated-sources/archetype`.

8) Em qualquer outra pasta fora da `seu-archetype-app-modelo`, crie uma pasta `seu-appweb-archetype`, execute o comando:

```
$cd ~/projetos && mkdir seu-appweb-archetype
```

9) Copie `seu-archetype-app-modelo/target/generated-sources/archetype` para  `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype`, execute o comanto:

```
$cp -Rf seu-archetype-app-modelo/target/generated-sources/archetype/ ~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype
```

Depois de copiar, devemos remover a pasta: `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype/target`.

10) Devemos editar o arquivo: `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml`. Substituir "*seu-archetype-app-modelo*" para ${artifactId}.

11) Devemos editar o arquivo: `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/AppStatusServlet.java`. Subestituir "*package ${package};*" para "*package ${package}.web.servlet;*".

**Pronto**! Para finalizar! Acesse a pasta  `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype` e execute:

```
mvn clean install
```

---

---

**Usando o Archetype**

No nosso caso o Archetype se encontra em `~/projetos/seu-appweb-archetype`, então devemos acessar `~/projetos` e executar o comando:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local \
-DgroupId=br.com.nome_novo_projeto \
-DartifactId=nome-novo-projeto \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Vai te solicitar que escolhar uma opção:

```
Choose archetype:
1: local -> br.com.seu_archetype_app_modelo:seu-archetype-app-modelo-archetype (seu-archetype-app-modelo-archetype)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :
```

Apenas digite `1`

Execute os comandos:

```
cd nome-novo-projeto && mvn tomcat7:run
```

E depois acesso o link: `http://localhost:8080/nome-novo-projeto/status`

---

---

<sub>**NOTA <sup>2</sup>**: Agora, temos o projeto Modelo: `seu-archetype-app-modelo` que foi criado com base no `maven-archetype-webapp`.</sub>

<sub>**NOTA <sup>3</sup>**: Qualquer melhoria do projeto modelo (`seu-archetype-app-modelo`), devemos repetir os passos 7-11.</sub>

<sub>**NOTA <sup>4</sup>**: Podes melhor a solução criando um *script shell* com os comandos, mas preferi realizar os passos manualmente para demosntrar melhor o funcionamento do uso de  *Archetype do maven*.</sub>

---

**Referência**:

<sub>[**Gonçalves, Antonio -  2013**], Apress, © 2013, **[Beginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O)** (Expert Voice in Java).</sub>
<sub>[**Juneau, Josh -  2013**], Apress, © 2013, **[Java EE 7 Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430244259)**: A problem-Solution Approach – Proven Solutions for Java Enterprise Edition 7 Developement.</sub>
<sub>[**Michal Cmil et al -  2014**], Copyright © 2014 Packt Publishing, **[Java EE 7 Development with WildFly](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly)**: Leverage the power of the WildFly application server from JBoss to develop modern Java EE 7 applications.</sub>
<sub>[**Tim O’Brien et al -  2010**], Copyright © 2010 Sonatype, Inc., **[The Maven Cookbook](http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/pdf/mcookbook-pdf.pdf)**: A Sonatype Open Book Mountain View, CA.</sub>
<sub>[**Balaji Varanasi, Sudha Belida -  2014**], Copyright © 2014 by Balaji Varanasi and Sudha Belida, **[Introducing Maven](https://www.apress.com/us/search?query=Introducing+Maven)**</sub>